# Inflating an xml vs. creating a new instance

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater

Are these two the same?

A.

my_custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.abc.views.MyCustomView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

MyCustomView.java

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

  public MyCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public static MyCustomView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    MyCustomView view = (MyCustomView) LayoutInflater.
    from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, parent, false);
    return view;
  }
```

B.

MyCustomView.java

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

  public MyCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public static MyCustomView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView(parent.getContext());
    parent.addChild(view);
    return view;
  }
```

When we run,

```
MyCustomView.inflate(parent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly.  Long story short, the differences here is in instance A, the LayoutParams will be set to "MATCH_PARENT" for the width and "WRAP_CONTENT" for the height.  In instance B, the LayoutParams will be whatever the default the parent View applies (usually WRAP_CONTENT for both width and height).

Additionally, in instance A, the view **is not attached** to the parent view.  In instance B, the view **is attached** to the parent view.

Long story long, here's other differences.

```
public static MyCustomView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    MyCustomView view = (MyCustomView) LayoutInflater.
    from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, parent, false);
    return view;
  }
```

This does a few things:

1. Inflates the view giving it layout parameters of the parent. If the
   parent is a FrameLayout, then the LayoutParams instance will be a
   `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.  If it is a LinearLayout, the
   LayoutParams will be a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. The layout
   parameters are assigned by the xml "layout_width" and
   "layout_height".  In this particular case, the width is set to `MATCH_PARENT` and the height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` (although this can be overridden by the parent View).
2. The view is **not** added or attached to the parent view as shown by
   the `false` parameter. (`true` will attach the view to the parent).
3. Any other attributes you eventually apply to the XML will be applied to the
   View.
4. The alternate constructors will be applied so the different
   attributes will be filled.  Which constructor is called is dependent on which attributes you apply.

   1. `View#(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`
   2. `View#(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)`
   3. `View#(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)`

On the other hand:

```
public static MyCustomView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView(parent.getContext());
    parent.addChild(view);
    return view;   
}
```

1. Default LayoutParams will be applied to the child view.  In most cases this is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` for both width and height, but it's up to the parent view to determine which.
2. The view **is attached** to the parent view.  If the caller were to try to add it to another parent view, it would result in a crash.
3. Absolutely no additional attributes are applied to the View.  They will have to be added manually.
4. Only the `View#(Context context)` constructor is used in creation.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate reply. This is very useful!